# Twilio PHP Lookup API is returning no response if number is not correct?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am trying to implement a Twilio Lookup API for validation of phone numbers are they correct or not.

What I have tried is a PHP [Lookup API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api)

```
$number = "+15445453"; // Wrong Number
$number = "+18186794307"; // Correct Number

$twilio = new Client($this->session->userdata('account_sid'), $this->session->userdata('auth_token'));
$phone_number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($number)->fetch(["type" => ["carrier"]]);
```

For the correct number, it is returning the response, whereas for the wrong number it's empty nothing response.

[image]

After digging some I found another solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354989/twilio-lookup-api-not-working) that is using curl and getter a response if a number is not correct.

```
$base_url = "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/" . $number;
$ch = curl_init($base_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account_sid:$auth_token" );

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);

echo "<pre>";   print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
```

[image]
[image]

What's the issue in PHP lookup API that I am missing to implement and  causing no response if a number is not correct?

Comment: @philnash #philnash or Twilio Geek Please assist me about the question

Answer (score 2):

It may be throwing an `Exception`.

See: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php/usage-guide#exceptions

I would assume you could do something like:

```php
$twilio = new Client(
    $this->session->userdata('account_sid'), 
    $this->session->userdata('auth_token')
);

try {
    $phone_number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($number)->fetch(["type" => ["carrier"]]);
} catch (TwilioException $e){
  echo $e->getCode();
}
```

Comment: I want the response of API, with parameters. (Like number is not verified etc)

Comment: I believe this is the answer. When a number is not found (ie it is invalid) in the Lookup API, the API returns a 404 error. This is thrown by the library as an exception which you should catch. The plain curl example works because curl is not throwing an error for a 404 response.